# How to limit PrimeNG Calendar Navigator to the set yearRange?

Tags: angular, primeng

I've set `p-calendar` to a specific `yearRange`, and use `minDate` to disable days outside my range. I'm using the `yearNavigator` and `monthNavigator` options. I'd like to know how I might prevent the `yearNavigator` select list from moving before or beyond my set range.

For instance, while my `yearRange` is set to `2019:2021` and dates before Jan 1, 2019 are disabled, a user can still navigate to January 2019 and click the prev arrow button to get to December 2018. The `yearNavigator` dropdown is then updated to show `2018:2020`. A user cannot select a disabled date, but I'd prefer to not show months in years that have no valid dates.

I can possibly use the `onMonthChange` event to check the date and disable/hide the prev arrow, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to prevent the `yearNavigator` from changing to a year outside the preset range?

```
<p-calendar
  formControlName="endDate"
  [required]="true"
  [minDate]="minDate"
  [monthNavigator]="true"
  [yearNavigator]="true"
  [yearRange]="2019:2021"
  [readonlyInput]="true"
  [showIcon]="true"
></p-calendar>
```